# Check if users match the same options

Tags: mysql, sql

So this is my table

```
|a_id|b_id|
|x   |y   |
|y   |x   |
|d   |c   |
|c   |d   |
|... |... |
```

many more...

what is the best way, to get all pairs ?
e.g from above example
(x and y) and (d and c)

I've never used sql without specific ids

Comment: Do you need only rows that have exactly one mirrored peer, or at least one mirrored peer, or just collapse duplicate (peer or not)? Is `(x,y)` a "pair" or is it `(x,y), (y,x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  t1.a_id
,       t1.b_id
from    YourTable t1
join    YourTable t2
on      t1.a_id = t2.b_id
        and t1.b_id = t2.a_id
where   t1.a_id > t2.a_id
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ecb0/3/0)

Comment: @Andomar - I didn't understand. if say table has only one row (k,l) and no swap row, it won't show up in your solution right?

Comment: @Brian: A single row cannot be part of a pair.  So yes.

Comment: @Andomar - Understood the question wrong.. got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a_id, b_id
FROM   TableName
WHERE  (LEAST(a_id, b_id), GREATEST(a_id, b_id), a_id) in 
(
    SELECT  LEAST(a_id, b_id) as x, 
            GREATEST(a_id, b_id) as y, 
            MIN(a_id) as a_id
    FROM    TableName 
    GROUP   BY x, y
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0d6e/3)

Comment: SQLFiddle is an amazing tool, btw.

Comment: offtopic, but what solution has better performance, join or this with second 'select' query ?

Answer (score 0):

Can be simpler:

```
SELECT LEAST(a_id, b_id) AS a, GREATEST(a_id, b_id) AS b 
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6fa1/1).

Comment: I don't think this ensures the returned rows are pairs.

Comment: @Andomar: I interpret `(x,y)` as "pair" and that we just need to collapse duplicates. You seem to understand it the way we need both `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` to qualify. The example in the question does not clarify which it should be.

Comment: Agreed on rereading. Nicely concise way to retrieve unique combinations of two colomns, +1